# Add FreeRTOS Kernel to an existing project in AtmelStudio

Tags: module, embedded, atmel, freertos, atmelstudio

I want add FreeRTOS Kernel to an existing project, [the references](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42382-Getting-Started-with-FreeRTOS-on-Atmel-SAM-Flash-MCUs_ApplicationNote_AT04056.pdf) I consult shows that this can be done using ASF Wizard.

[image]

However in the ASF 3.30.1 (the version i have in my PC) I cannot find FreeRTOS module

[image]

I am not sure I undrestand why the freeRTOS module doesn't exist. Also I do not want to import freeRTOS source files from another project(this will be the last choice).

I am using Atmel Studio version 7.0.1006

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure the search is not case sensitive (_"Free"_ vs _"free"_) - worth checking perhaps. A problem with relying on IDE built-in support for third-party libraries is that either party may withdraw or cease to maintain that support at any time; however this is not indicated in the release notes.   In the long term you might be better off importing the code yourself.  It may even be useful to built the library separately and statically link it.  That may make sharing across projects and porting to different tool-chains easier.

Comment: no, the module really don't exist, i download an example project for EVK1100 and start to include the sources of my application one by one, i find configuration problems (clock freq, ...).the problem come from the fact that these params exists in the freeRTOS project example and the compiler read the params not from my application sources but from freeRTOS project sources, because in the Makefile, -DBOARD=EVK1100 is passed to the compiler instead of -DBOARD=USER_BOARD, the Makefile is created by the IDE so i don't want to edit it.

Comment: from your experience could you give us "the best practises for including freeRTOS to an existing application", is it better to start with an freeRTOS project and include the applications files or the opposite, what are the things that i should pay attention?

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to add the code in manually then there are instructions here: http://www.freertos.org/Creating-a-new-FreeRTOS-project.html .  The Atmel Studio demo projects in the FreeRTOS download have the code added manually so you can use those as a reference - you will find a list here http://www.freertos.org/a00090.html#ATMEL

Comment: Yes,  this is what i try to do now, thanks for the references

Comment: in the freeRTOS project example i downloaded, i find that -D__FREERTOS__ is also passed to the compiler, so maybe it can cause problems, ok for including the .c and header files, for the exception.s what is it's purpose ?, if i have an exception.s in my application what should i do?,the Makefile should i edit it manually? is there other things that i should pay attention?

Comment: @fedi : SO is not a discussion forum.  If you have new questions post new questions.

Comment: @Clifford, Added [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401359/problems-while-importing-freertos-to-at32uc3a0512), hope you could help me, thanks in advance.