# problems while importing freeRTOS to AT32UC3A0512

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, rtos, freertos

i am attempting to integrate freeRTOS to my application that run on AT32UC3A0512.
I downloaded a freeRTOS project example for [EVK1100](http://www.atmel.com/tools/EVK1100.aspx) (it Supports the AT32UC3A) and try to include the kernel source file
so my application hierarchy looks like :

```
src
   |ASF
   |APP_FOLDER
   |freertos 
       |freertos-7.0.0
```

this hierarchy is different than the the hierarchy provided in the freeRTOS project example which looks like

```
  src
   |ASF
       |thirdparty
          |freertos 
              |freertos-7.0.0   /********** freertos-7.0.0 is under ASF***********/
```

1 - This has caused compilation problems(path of some file not recognized) that i have solved, and i don't think that it can lead to other issues. what do you think?

now it seems also that i have problems with `exception.s`

```
  /*my actual appli hierarchy*/
  src
   |ASF
      |AVR32
         |intc
              |exception.s
   |APP_FOLDER
   |freertos 
       |freertos-7.0.0
          |source
              |portable
                  |gcc
                      |avr32_uc3
                          |exception.S
```

As you see the file is redefined,i came to [this solution](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/solved-multiple-definition-evba-compile-error) that consist in removing `exception.s` under `intc` folder, now the project compiles but there is calls to `twi_master_read` in my application that cause blocking, i haven't changed anything in my application(which use to work normally) i didn't call any freeRTOS api function yet,

2- could you please help me undrestand the the purpose of `exception.s`, and what leaded to this unexpected behaviour ?

3- Could this problem come from the non respect of the hierarchy ?

Don't hesitate to comment on my choices or suggest better practices on importing freeRTOS kernel ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I removed exception.s from `freertos-7.0.0/source/portable/gcc/avr32_uc3/exception.S` and keep the exception.s file of my starting application, Now using the application hierarchy mentioned above if i exclude freertos directory from the project all works well, if i include the freertos directory `twi_master_read` causes problems, There is any pins redefinitions in the kernel files and i didn't call/include freeRTOS API at all so how the behaviour changes this way ?